# Unable to catch error in a for await of loop

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm was reading about the "for await of loop" as [described on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of). It looks impressive, so I played a bit with some code, but I'm surprisingly being unable to catch errors thrown there.

```
'use strict';

const main = async() => {
  const bar = [];
  bar.push(new Promise((res) => { setTimeout(() => res(1), 1200); }));
  bar.push(new Promise((res) => { setTimeout(() => res(2), 800); }));
  bar.push(new Promise((res, rej) => { setTimeout(() => rej(3), 200); }));

  try {
    for await (const foo of bar) {
      console.log('hey', foo);
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('err', err);
  }
};

main();
```

My output is like I expect, mainly. But I can't understand, why I'm getting an UnhandledPromiseRejection? Didn't I even catch that error?

```
$> node await-loop.js 
(node:10704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 3
(node:10704) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10704) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
hey 1
hey 2
err 3
(node:10704) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

Can somebody please help me understand and write a correct catch-phrase here? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

> UnhandledPromiseRejection?
>
> Didn't I even catch that error?

Theoretically, yes. (Well thats what the catch block is for right?)

Technically no.

```
Main Stack
|  try             |
|                  |
|    await bar[0]  | <-- waiting to resolve till sometime after 1200
|                  |
|  catch           |
|                  |
```

**After (approx) 200 millis**:

bar[2] is rejected and pushed to the queue, but await did not yield because it was still waiting for bar[0] to yield which happens only after 1200 millis

So, at the time bar[2] was rejected *no `catch` block was available* to handle the `rejected promise`. See the above stack and note that `try..catch` and `bar[2]` are not in the *same stack* at the time of rejection, well, atleast to the compiler(or conceptually for javascript).

But you notice: `err 3` which the catch block catches when finally await yields `bar[2]`

If you change the order of promises and put the rejected promise as first item in the array, you'll see the catch block worked nicely.

Or awaiting the differently:

```
// unhandled rejection
try {
  await bar[0]
  await bar[1]
  await bar[2]
} catch (e) {
  console.error('error', e)
}

// Catch successfull
try {
  await bar[2]
  await bar[0]
  await bar[1]
} catch (e) {
  console.error('error', e)
}
```

Update:

A better approach would be to use `Promise.all`, it have a fail-fast behaviour.

```
try {
  const datas = await Promise.all(bar)
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your solution isn't practically, since I need to actually _know_ whatever async-function is throwing an error (or in this case rejecting the promise). Do you mind a solution of catching that error without rearranging my calls?

Comment: Thank you again, for updating your answer. But I think you didn't catch my approach. I'm actually trying to catch an error while using a `for await of` loop. If approachable, I would use `Promise.all` of course. My example should only showcase, what's needed to reproduce my situation. I still whish to use a `for await of` loop, looping over asynchronous functions _and_ still able to catch errors if they occur.

Comment: Like I said in the solution, it would not be possible. `async/await` is just a syntatic sugar. behind the scene it uses `generators`. While waiting for a promise to `yield` some other promise in the array might have failed so within the generator function there would be not catch block in scope to handle the rejection

Answer (score 0):

A `for await of` loop is just shorthand syntax for a synchronous `for of` loop with an `await` in the loop body. So you can achieve what you want with this:

```js
'use strict';

const main = async() => {
  const bar = [];
  bar.push(new Promise((res) => { setTimeout(() => res(1), 1200); }));
  bar.push(new Promise((res) => { setTimeout(() => res(2), 800); }));
  bar.push(new Promise((res, rej) => { setTimeout(() => rej(3), 200); }));

  for (const foo of bar) {
    try { 
      const result = await foo;
      console.log('hey', result);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('err', err);
    }
  }
};

main();
```

Incidentally, if you want to know what promise threw the error then `Promise.allSettled` might be closer to what you want and cleaner code:

```js
'use strict';

const main = async() => {
  const bar = [];
  bar.push(new Promise((res) => { setTimeout(() => res(1), 1200); }));
  bar.push(new Promise((res) => { setTimeout(() => res(2), 800); }));
  bar.push(new Promise((res, rej) => { setTimeout(() => rej(3), 200); }));

  const results = await Promise.allSettled(bar);
  
  /* Outputs:
  [
  { status: 'fulfilled', value: 1 },
  { status: 'fulfilled', value: 2 },
  { status: 'rejected', reason: 3 }
]
  */
  console.log(results);
};

main();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But working around the issue, is just that: a work around.